# Detect Browser lost focus in CSS

Tags: html, css

I saw this functionality in a design a while back and thought "hay, that looks like a good idea". But looking further into it, I'm not sure it's entirely possible using 'just css'.

There was a navigation bar down the left hand side:

```css
ul{
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3</li>
  <li>link 4</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to change this when the browser window looses focus?

I.e. when the user clicks off the browser, to make this nav's background color, for example, change?

---

The only *possible* (probably more *inefficient* way would be to do something like):

```css
body:hover ul {
  background: red;
}
body ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3</li>
  <li>link 4</li>
</ul>
```

that i could think of.

But this obviously

- (A) doesn't work well
- (B) doesn't actually do this correctly.

---

It's more that I would like the browser to physically 'lose focus' before changing the css.

Would anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Using CSS this is not possible. Are you open to other methods to achieve this? Also I feel the hover body method is not a good one, if you where to move your mouse up to the top of your browser it would look a bit cheap and tacky.

Comment: @Ruddy: I suppose JQuery's the alternative?

Comment: There's a [recent (Jan 2015) article in smashingmagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/20/creating-sites-with-the-page-visibility-api/) that debates previous approaches to seeing if a tab is visible alongside an upcoming API for this purpose. (But: it is all JS approaches.)

Comment: @jbutler483 [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/afa63a0k/embedded/result/), thats how you can do it in jQuery (the ony way I know) but its pretty much the same thing as hover.

Comment: @jbutler483 But using this method would be betteras it determines if the page is still in focus (unlike hover).

Comment: Why do you care to change the color of something when someone is not looking at it?

Comment: Probably for the same reason an OS changes the style of inactive windows.

Comment: @SalmanA: It was more than just 'background color'. I was thinking of something like an inactive design (i've seen it used on stuff like chrome's tabs section/window) so thought it'd be cool to implement something similar.

Answer (score 5):

Neither the current nor upcoming CSS standards define any selector or media query for when the user agent is not in the foreground.<sup>1</sup>

The [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility) mentioned in the comments doesn't quite do what you're looking for, as that does not tell you whether the browser is in the foreground, only whether the page is visible. A browser window can be in the background but its current tab can still be visible if the window isn't minimized or isn't being completely obscured by another window (and you won't even get consistent results with the latter with the aforementioned API).

The best you can do is to listen for window focus and blur events using JavaScript:

```js
window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  document.body.classList.add('blur');
});

window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  document.body.classList.remove('blur');
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.blur ul {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3</li>
  <li>link 4</li>
</ul>
```

The caveat is that this will not work correctly if the page is in an iframe (such as in a Stack Snippet, as above), since the iframe's `window` object will lose focus when the iframe itself loses focus.

I am not aware of any methods to reliably detect when the browser window becomes active or inactive.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Firefox uses a `:-moz-window-inactive` pseudo-class internally which works exactly as you would expect, but obviously this is a browser-specific feature and as such shouldn't be used in production code:</sub>

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}
ul:-moz-window-inactive {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3</li>
  <li>link 4</li>
</ul>
```

<sub>WebKit has its own `:window-inactive` pseudo-class as well, which is actually what inspired the same feature in Firefox, except that WebKit does not prefix it for some strange reason, and it currently only applies to scrollbar pseudo-elements.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You definitely cannot detect focus on window in css since css executed in scope of document. But you can detect it on, say `body`, using html5 `tabindex` attribute:

```css
body:focus ul {
  background: red;
}
body ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body tabindex="0">
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
    <li>link 4</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *try* [`:window-inactive`](http://css-tricks.com/window-inactive-styling/):

```
::selection {
  background: hsl(136,65%,45%);
  color: white;
}
::selection:window-inactive {
  background: hsl(136,25%,65%);
}
```

It is implemented [at least in firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-window-inactive), and you can see it working on [its test page (firefox only)](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/moz-window-inactive.html).